# Rails 3: How to display a warning message when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have the following link in my Rails 3 application:

```
link_to("Invoice", "/jobs/#{job.id}/invoice")
```

When user clicks it, the application shows an invoice.

I would like to display a warning message when `job.price` is missing, asking the user whether to continue or not. Then, it should be redirected to the invoice page only if user chose "yes".

What is the easiest way to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
link_to("Invoice", "/jobs/#{job.id}/invoice", 
        :confirm => (job.price ? '' : "Job Price is missing. Continue anyway ?"))
```

Comment: Does that pop up an empty confirm box w/ the empty string?  If it does try making the first ternary option `nil` instead.  Maybe that works though.

Comment: It doesn't pop up with empty string!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Invoice", "/jobs/#{job.id}/invoice", :onclick => "#{ "confirm('The job price is missing, are you sure you want to continue?')" if job.price.nil? } %>
```

Hope that's what you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: These answers are very non-rails-y.  Why would you define your own onclick handler when Rails3 gives you unobtrusive javascript ways of doing this for free ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Prototype.js, the easiest thing would probably be an inline click handler. The built-in :confirm option won't work since you need to check a field on the page.

```
link_to("Invoice", "/jobs/#{job.id}/invoice", :onclick => "if($F('job_price') == '') confirm('Job price is not set. Are you sure you want to continue?');")
```

There are probably a hundred more sophisticated ways of handling this, unobtrusively or whatever.

Comment: The answer the OP posted will work, with checking the field on the page.