# Rails: Display alert before redirecting to external site

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to link to an external site, but before I do, I want to display a dialog box that says something like "You are being redirected". I tried using `flash.now["alert"]` for this but was having no luck; I only saw my message after redirecting first and going back to my site.

My template contains a form with a select box and depending on which option is selected, the visitor will either be directed to another page on the site or to an external site.

In the controller, there is an instance variable set to the value that was stored in the database. Depending on that value, it'll either redirect to the external site or to the internal page.

How can I display a small alert before redirecting to the external site? If this has to be done in javascript, how can I pass the value of the instance variable to the javascript?

Comment: yes this can accomplished with javascript but you should try it self and if you can't, come here and ask question with code.

Comment: I'm asking if it HAS to be accomplished with javascript because I'd rather do it with ruby instead if that's possible.

Comment: this should be on client-side, so i think with `Ruby` no chance.

Comment: It's accomplished with Javascript, but there's a helper in Rails which puts in the JS for you. So yes, with Ruby a chance.

Comment: The "flash hash" is only for adding content to the user's next request - it doesn't help much on the client side, as you've discovered. You might want to read up on how it's used.

Comment: @pjmorse Yep, I read that but I thought I could use flash.now to display it before the redirect. Not the case apparently.

Answer (score 0):

This can fairly easily be accomplished without javascript.

Simply make a model called OffsiteLinks, or something. That model would have the external url. The show path for the object would redirect to the external resource. This is nice, because you don't need to display the external link, worry about rel nofollow stuff, and you can do things like increment a hit counter before redirecting.

If you want to display the real link, you are pretty much stuck with javascript.

Actually, I'm sorry. I misread part of your question. You will pretty much need javascript to display the message, or perform the redirect, if you require the message...

You could get around this by displaying a "OK take me there link" on the resulting page, for users without js...

Answer (score 0):

Rails' `link_to` helper allows for a `confirm: message` option which does what you want. What you want to do is define a helper:

```
def link_to_external(body, url)
  link_to body, url, :confirm => 'You are being redirected'
end
```

Now you can use `link_to_external` instead of `link_to` in your templates:

```
link_to_external "Somewhere else", "http://example.com/"
```

You could make that helper more robust to support all the options of `link_to` (and allow for a custom confirmation message) if you wanted to spend the time.

If you just want to make one link like this, you can just use `link_to`:

```
link_to "Somewhere else", "http://example.com/", confirm: 'You are being redirected'
```

...as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241722/306084).

Comment: Just to be clear, the [confirm message uses javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: It does. But you don't need to write the javascript yourself, which is my point. The OP doesn't make clear if they have a restriction preventing use of Javascript in the app, or if they just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, this won't work in this case because there's actually no link used in the template. There's a form with a select box and in the controller, depending on which value was selected, the visitor will either be directed to an on-site page or to the external site.

Comment: @dagarre Then yes, you're out of luck. Your last chance to interact with the user comes when they click the button to submit your form. You'll need custom JS to check the contents of the form and decide whether or not to show the warning.